# How to connect two internal networks with Sophos

Tags: networking

How can i connect two networks to each other with Sophos?

I've tried adding static routing, however this didn't work. I've also tried adding firewall rules.

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:sophoslabs-intelix], but that doesn't seem to have anything to do with connecting networks. It isn't clear if you just have **completely** the wrong idea about what the API or if which Sophos product you are using if you selected that tag in error. Note that whatever product you are talking about, this sounds like a network administration problem, not a programming problem, so is off-topic for this site.